# Start app from within python

Tags: python

I'm trying to start an application using Python. I've seen that some people use startfile but I also read that it only works with Windows. I'm using Mac systems and hoping for it to work with them.
Thanks,
Aaron

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `os.system("/path/to/myapp")`.

See http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.system for documentation.

If you want more control over the process being executed, check out the [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess) module instead.

Answer (score 4):

Python has the subprocess module for that, you can read about it here: http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html

In it's simplest form:

```
subprocess.call(['your_command', 'params'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using [os.system](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.system) - the docs say it is supported on UNIX and Windows, but since OSX is UNIX-based I would expect it to work on that platform as well.